# Email Verifcation using Regex

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

I have problem with my email regex
its not allowing this type: a_a@domain.com
it doesn't allow  "_" symbol (underscore )

i want to be able to validate emails in this format too
a_a@domain.com

```
/^(?!.*_)\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})/
```

Comment: where and how, there alot of \w

Comment: nvm I reviewed what `\w` means: *\w matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])* so should already be including `_`

Comment: Remove the negative-look-ahead - `(?!.*_)` - this says: don't match anything with a `_`

Comment: sorry its not working

Comment: To match that email address `^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,3}$` See https://regex101.com/r/BwC6x9/1 But why do you have the negative lookahead `(?!.*_)` in your pattern? Did you want to rule out the `_` somewhere in the email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex proposed here (https://regex101.com/r/BwC6x9/1) works fine for your asked question.
If you want to ensure the email adress is not starting by an underscore but only a letter in [a-z] then:

1. you could have written this requirement in your question!
2. it's a good idea to check this!
3. this regex should do the job : `^[a-z]\w*(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,3}$` see https://regex101.com/r/n8T7OY/1
4. you can do the same for domain part of the regex (domain should not start with underscore)

However, if you want to match email adress and have a good and complete solution look this question and answers: [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)